# Netboot and install from internet

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation

I am trying to do [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/NetbootInstallFromInternet) ,like the title says. 
I have retrieved the 2 necessary files and placed them in /boot
Then I rebooted, went into Grub2

Now however, i am not getting grub to recognise the paths. Or else I am doing something really wrong:
As I said, I have booted into Grub2, having previously placed both files inside /boot
So, the syntax for me in steps 2 and 3 should be:

```
linux /boot/linux
```

and

```
initrd /boot/initrd.gz.
```

But I am getting 'No such partition'

I am missing something obvious.. but what?

Help, as always, would be appreciated

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `root` correctly. Either look in your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` for the first line which starts with `set root=`. E.g:

```
set root='(hd0,msdos5)'
```

Or use uuid look up:

```
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root YOUR_PARTITIONS_UUID_HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about placement of those two required files in /boot then the only place you can do mistake is Step 1.

I mean

```
root=(hd0,0)
```

as they are saying

> Replace the root partition with the drive and partition on which your
>   /boot is located. You can look at and copy the root line of any
>   existing boot menu entry if you are at all unsure what this is, or you
>   can try tab-completing after root ( or root (hd0,

To know your root partition , there it self type as

```
root
```

and then press a TAB key , it will automatically choose that.

hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for responding! you are probably right that things went wrong in the first step. I rechecked my partitioning and /boot is sda2 on hd0. So i'm assung in step 1 I need to put root=(hd0,2). When I enter that, it no longer says 'No such partition'. Succes right! wrong :) When I enter the path to linux like mentioned above, I get 'file /boot/linux' not found, although I am sure it is there (i did an ls -l to doublecheck). Can this be a rights issue?

Comment: hmm apparently not. I chmoded the owner to root for both files, and chowned so root had rwx on both. No change though. I even granted all rights to all owners (after a succesfull net install, this will be overwriten anyway right?), but even that doesn't help. Still the error is: file '/boot/linux' not found.. So I'm still stuck on this